# Has anyone been able to delete/delist a package from VsTeams Package Server feature?

Tags: package, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

Trying from Nuget.exe I just get an endless loop of authentication requests...

I am fed up.  Why can't they just put a darn button in Visual Studio Team  Services itself that lets you remove them directly off the darn host.

I am about to just setup my own network shared package server for my team.

I can host packages, I can pick them up in Visual Studio, but no way to delete/delist them using nuget.exe as far as I can see.

It bothers me that they will have to go to two different places, but that's how this looks right now.

Comment: I suppose you' went through: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/remove

Comment: And this part may be important: "Note: If this fails with error code 404, you may be using a NuGet v3 URL. Be sure you use a NuGet v2 URL."

Comment: Been there, done that yes.  I just get prompted for authentication endlessly.  I can push the package up with the same tools and credentials.  Delisting seems to have some trick to it.  I really don't understand why MS didn't just add a delist button in TFS itself.  It is ridiculous that we have to delist packages from nugget.exe when we admin the package server.

Comment: The button is coming as part of the current deployment :). Should be about 2 or 3 days out.

Comment: What's the result if you authenticate with personal access token and delete package (steps in my answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps below to authenticate with personal Access Token instead (works fine for me).

1. Open your profile and go to security details page
2. Add a new personal access tokens
3. Run this command to add package source with username and password (PAT): nugget sources add -name “xxx” -source [feed package resource url e.g. https://starain.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/FeedStarainTest/nuget/v3/index.json] -username “Xxx” -password “[your personal access token]”
4. Run nugget command to delete package: nugget.exe delete [package id] [version] -source [XXX] -ApiKey VSTS
   [image]
   On the other hand, for the feature of a button to delete package directly on VSTS, as Alex said that you can check next update.